# MalformatedInputException with Utility.convertByteArrayToCharArray and MessageDigest

Tags: java, java-7

I'm trying to create a glassfish custom JDBCRealm and during some test on it, I got a MalformatedInputException when I using the com.sun.enterprise.util.Utility.convertByteArrayToCharArray function.

So I decided to externalize the part of my function which throw this error to test it and understand where it comming.

Resumed function:

```
public void justATestFunction()
        throws Exception
{
    final char[] password = "myP4ssW0rd42".toCharArray();
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    // according to the Utility doc, if the Charset parameter is null or empty,
    // it will call the Charset.defaultCharset() function to define the charset to use
    byte[] hashedPassword= Utility.convertCharArrayToByteArray(password, null);
    hashedPassword = md.digest(hashedPassword);
    Utility.convertByteArrayToCharArray(hashedPassword, null); // throw a MalformatedInputException
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Post the actual COMPLETE stack trace, not your paraphrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at each step:

```
byte[] hashedPassword= Utility.convertCharArrayToByteArray(password, null);
```

The above converts the Unicode-16 characters to a byte-array using the default endcoding, probably WIN-1252 or UTF-8. Since the password contains nothing outside standard 7-bit ASCII, the result is the same for either encoding.

```
hashedPassword = md.digest(hashedPassword);
```

`hashedPassword` now refers to a completely different byte array containing the BINARY digest of the original password.  This is a BINARY string and no longer represents anything in any character encoding.  It is pure binary data.

```
Utility.convertByteArrayToCharArray(hashedPassword, null);
```

Now you attempt to "decode" the binary string as if it were encoded with the default character set, which will undoubtedly throw an exception.

I suspect you really wanted to display either the hexadecimal representation of the digest, or maybe the base-64 version. In either case, what you have done will never work.

Since you haven't explained what you want to accomplish, this is the best anyone can do.